# php preg_replace part of long string

Tags: php, regex

I have a database with these long descriptions and I need to figure out how to extract a location code from the description. I'm using `preg_replace()` to match it like this example entry.

```
$string = "Honda 1982 VF750C Magna right-side radiator trim panel. Good, damage-free condition. Needs cut and polished. Cheap, fast shipping! 011425 H6 <img src=\">http://www.roofis27.com/motorcycle/10_01_14/030.JPG\"> n=\">";
$pattern = '(\d\d\d\d\d\d\s\D\d)'; 
$replace = '$1';
echo 'Replaced String: ' . preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string) . '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo 'Original String: ' . $string;
```

What I need to do is remove everything **BUT** the `011425 H6` in the `$string`. I cannot figure out how to rid the rest of the string. I can match the pattern, but what regex do I use to remove the rest of the string? More less remove everything before and after the `011425 H6`. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance :)

Comment: is it always in front of the `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small modification, then it should work:

```
<?php

$string = "Honda 1982 VF750C Magna right-side radiator trim panel. Good, damage-free condition. Needs cut and polished. Cheap, fast shipping! 011425 H6 <img src=\">http://www.roofis27.com/motorcycle/10_01_14/030.JPG\"> n=\">";
$pattern = '/^.*\b(\d\d\d\d\d\d\s\D\d)\b.*$/';
$replace = '$1';
echo 'Replaced String: ' . preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string) . '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo 'Original String: ' . $string;
```

Comment: Awesome, I thought it was something like that but I was stuck using `^(\d\d\d\d\d\d\s\D\d)$`. Do you have any good references for learning regex, BETTER :)

Comment: All I read was [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) from O'Reilly. Can definitely recommend it, though.